# MySQL Syntax Error insert into

Tags: mysql, database

This is my SQL query

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
    VALUES ($username, $encryptedpass, $email, 0)
```

I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , 0)' at line 2

Could you please explain where I am messing up, and how to fix it

Comment: You're missing some of these : '

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your values in single quotes (assuming `Admin` is an integer):

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
    VALUES ('$username', '$encryptedpass', '$email', 0)
```

For best practice, you should encase all system keywords in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`Username`, `Password`, `Email`, `Admin`)
    VALUES ('$username', '$encryptedpass', '$email', 0)
```

If you're using PHP to send this data, you should be using [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) using [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/pdo).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if that was a simple question, I just am new to MySQL. And, yes I am using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your variables with `'` to correctly format your variables. Integer fields do not require enclosure.

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
VALUES ('$username', '$encryptedpass', '$email', 0)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I needed them all to be surrounded by 's

Comment: @speedysnail6 if the 0 needed to be enclosed then that field is not expecting an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
VALUES ('$username', '$encryptedpass', '$email', '0')
```

or

```
 INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
VALUES ('$username', '$encryptedpass', '$email', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if that was a simple question, I just am new to MySQL. And, yes I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
    VALUES ($username, $encryptedpass, $email, 0)
```

Should be

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
    VALUES ('$username', '$encryptedpass', '$email', '0')
```

The problem was that an empty string was not being inserted it was being read as

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
    VALUES (, , , 0)
```

When all three variables were empty strings instead of

```
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
    VALUES ('', '', '', '0')
```

The empty string `''` tells MySQL to empty the empty string instead of go to the next value with `,`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if that was a simple question, I just am new to MySQL. And, yes I am using PHP.

Comment: @Speedysnail6 no problem, we all started somewhere and got stomped with simple stuff like this along the way. Just remember to keep the manuals at a handy shortcut [php.net](http://www.php.net) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index.html) And help out by accepting what you think is the best answer with the green checkmark and any helpful answers with the ^

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP? Text date must go between ''

INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email, Admin)
    VALUES ('$username', '$encryptedpass', '$email', 0)